# How do you deal with impersonators

Tags: discussion, support, phishing

So I found the following link on my FaceBook feed: `http://stackov.erflow.ru`. And being an obvious phishing site I wanted to ask if there is a policy for SO (or other SE sites) for reporting such impersonators?

To clarify: this site does scrape the content without attribution, but the main point is that it's using it to phish for SO users' credentials.

Comment: You should also [report phishing](https://www.google.com/safebrowsing/report_phish/) as I just did

Comment: Hi, I'm Eimantas. Thanks for the good answers and comments.

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate. That question is about content getting cloned under a different site name, without even using the name "stackoverflow" or variation of it. On the opposite, the present question does not even talk about content: it is about impersonation/phishing, which is a different topic and valid even if content cloning is not happening together.

Comment: And they load the website resources from SO CDN. How rude..

Comment: I would just hit the "contact us" link at the bottom of the page (of this site, not the phishing site ;P) and explain the situation. Do be sure to mention that's it's phishing, not content replication. There are recourses for Stack Overflow around trademark infringement if not copyright...

Comment: Hey, I'm Eimantas.  Could you please answer this comment with your username and password?  Thanks.

Comment: @Yakk The username is `cat` and the password is `cat`. Thankfully, it does not seem that http://stackov.erflow.ru actually tries to collect login data.

Comment: For shits and giggles you should report them directly from http://stackov.erflow.ru/contact

Comment: I tried signing in with my Google account but they want me to sign in with the form. They're bad impersonators if they can't use OAuth.

Comment: Related - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-do-i-do

Answer (score 14):

If they're actually using StackOverflow data without proper attribution as specified in the [CC BY SA License](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), you can report them to the SE Team by clicking the  [Contact us](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) link located in the footer of every SE site.

From the List of reasons there, pick "Stack Exchange content is being reproduced without attribution".

In addition to this, you can report the post advertising this site to facebook directly.

Comment: The question does not talk about "*using StackOverflow data*".

Comment: @NicolasRaoul The website is, though, and not with proper attribution. And thats the only thing SE can do anything about.

Comment: It might, but that's not the topic of the question. Cheers :-)